# Increment !:1 value in csh alias

Tags: shell, math, arguments, alias, tcsh

I'm trying to create a shortcut to find the n'th most recently updated folder at a location in a cshell terminal. Currently I have one to find the latest one.

```
alias latest    'cd `ls -dt1 -- */ | head -1`'
```

I'm looking to add an argument so it can calculate the nth most recent folder with something like

```
alias latestn 'cd `ls -dt1 -- */ | head -[expr !:1 + 1] | tail 1`'
```

I've tried searching on the site but I can't find an example for performing math on input argument.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to perform mathematical operations on your input argument. By doing this:

```bash
alias latestn 'cd `ls -dt1 -- */ | tail -n+\!:1 | head -1`'
```

The command `latestn 1` will go to the newest directory  (1st most recent), `latestn 2` will go to the 2nd most recent directory, etc.

This is because `tail -n+x` is retrieving lines starting from line `x`, and `head -1` is getting the first one: hence, chaining both is equivalent to getting the `x`th line.